# How do you use ToList with an SQL view in C#? Pains with Invalid object name dbo.*

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I need to get a List from a query involving a view.  Here's the code:

```cs
IEnumerable<Link> links = _db.Links.Include("User").Include("ModUser");
return View(links.ToList());
```

My people view has two one-to-many relations to the above Links table, in User and ModUser.  The ToList call throws a EntityCommandExecutionException, with "Invalid object name 'dbo.Person'."  How can I get this data into a list?

Comment: You need to fix your entity schema

Comment: possible duplicate of [When querying a view in ASP.NET C# MVC 3, why am I having trouble with ToList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636437/when-querying-a-view-in-asp-net-c-sharp-mvc-3-why-am-i-having-trouble-with-toli)

Comment: *Possible* duplicate? OP - please remove one of these posts so it can be addressed in one place...

Comment: It was a duplicate.  Sorry, I'll remove the other.

Comment: @SLaks, it seems I do have schema problems.  I'm using code first.  This is my first time without a tutorial, and integration's a little rough.  How do I do the mapping?  Does the EF map automatically with <name>ID model properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a nube it's embarrassing.  I was trying to access a View named Persons.  Way back when it was made they named it People.  My DBA changed it and I eventually got it working.